# pass this keyword to a function of imported class

Tags: javascript, class, import

while calling a imported class I'm trying to pass this to *myFunction()*:

one.js:

```
import Two from './two'
new Two(this)
```

two.js:

```
export default class two extends bla.blabla{
  constructor(that) {
    super()
    this.myFunction(that)
  }

  myFunction(that) {
    that.input.on('pointerdown', () => {
      //do something
    });
  }
}
```

but I get error from *two.js*: "Cannot read property 'on' of undefined"

How can I do this?

Comment: What is `this` in `one.js`?

Comment: `this` should be `window` on a browser, or it will be `undefined` on node. Anyhow, what is the exact error? `that` is undefined or cannot find `on` on undefined?

Comment: @Programmer this refers to a framework in one.js

Comment: @izhaki yes "Cannot read property 'on' of undefined" edited

Comment: I think that if you `console.log(this)` on `one.js` it'll spit `undefined`. I guess you are running this on node.

Comment: @izhaki actually no, it refers to a framework that i have imported in one.js, if i put all myFunction(){..} in one.js it works perfectly. I'm putting it in a separate file just so I have a clean code

Comment: `this` within `myFunction(){ ... }` will point to `myFunction`. But it seems that in `one.js` it is sibling to the import statement, where `this` should resolve to undefined. Why would `this` in `one.js` be anything else? Can you share `console.log(this)` if you put it in `one.js`?

Comment: @izhaki you where right. `console.log(this)` in `one.js` is undefined. it wasn't first but i did some changes and i didn't notice that it's now undefined... Idk why i didn't test it first... thanks for mentioning it works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` in `one.js` is probably undefined.

It seems to be a root level statement running on node - hence it will resolve to `undefined`.